# How to troubleshoot SAP B1 Addon connection timed out?

Tags: sapb1

Last week, one computer unit was using SAP B1 with addon running smoothly and I reprogram the computer for upgrade and re-install sap, however SAP was running okay but cannot connect to Addon. Any ideas how to solve the problem?

**Screenshot:**

[image: addon connection timed out sap b1]

Answer (score 0):

If you use that addon in other computers and have no problems, try uninstalling the addon completely from SAP client and from Add/Remove programs from windows, restart the computer and then reinstall add-on from the SAP.

Answer (score 0):

That's the way addon connection works:

1. your configured addon is started by B1 with a connection string and waits for the addon to connect back to B1
2. the addon read the connection string and get connected back to B1
3. if the addon does not connect back to B1 after 10 seconds then a timeout error is raised and B1 keeps on running

Your addon is not killed anyway. So this is what most likely happened. Check your code and see when you connect back and with which connection string when it gets started from B1.

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here try
        {
            log.Info("DI-Verbindung aufbauen.");
            Company = new Company
            {
                DbServerType = GetServerType(Configuration.Servertype),
                Server = Configuration.Server,
                LicenseServer = Configuration.Lizenzserver,
                language = BoSuppLangs.ln_German,
                UseTrusted = false,
                DbUserName = Configuration.DBUser,
                DbPassword = Configuration.DBPass,
                CompanyDB = Configuration.SBOCompany,
                UserName = Configuration.SBOUser,
                Password = Configuration.SBOPass
            };

            log.Info("Verbindung zur SAP-Datenbank " + Configuration.SBOCompany + " auf Server " + Configuration.Server + " wird aufgebaut.");
            int result = Company.Connect();

            if (result != 0)
            {
                Company.GetLastError(out int lErrCode, out string sErrMsg);
                throw new ObjektusException(sErrMsg);
            }
            else
            {
                log.Info("Verbindung zur SAP-Datenbank " + Configuration.SBOCompany + " auf Server " + Configuration.Server + " erfolgreich aufgebaut.");
            }
```